# Eclipse Find/Replace not working

Tags: eclipse, replace, find

I have searched for a solution to my problem but with no avail. The eclipse Find/Replace function found by the hotkey ctrl+F is not working. Note: the function does not work by the hotkey neither by going through Eclipse menu Edit>Find Replace (not working I mean that the FindReplace window does not show at all, the eclipse window loses focus only). I have tried to disable the hotkey to see if it would work, restarted eclipsed, restarted the PC, but nothing seems to solve the problem. It was working just fine but then suddenly out of the blue it just decided not to function anymore. Everything I tried so far has failed. As I use this function often it would be nice to know if someone has another input for trying to solve this bug. I am on a PC with windows 7, intel i7 64-bits.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Check the checkboxes. ;)

Comment: Not working how? Is the dialog displaying? Does Find work? Is it Replace that does not work? Have you set any of the check boxes such as 'Whole word' or 'Regular expressions' which change how it works?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. The window of find/replace does not show. It seems that the eclipse window loses focus and the expected find/replace window does not show! I also have edited my question....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar issue after using second monitor at work. At home I was wondering where is my Find/Replace window... it was displayed at the second monitor as I used it last time... Eclipse stores the last location of the dialogs for better UX.

So try to move the Find/Replace window by using your keyboard.

[How to Move an Open Window with the Keyboard](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/77361-move-window-keyboard.html)

---

You can also try to reset perspective

```
Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...
```

Comment: It solved my problem by reseting the perspective, love you man!

Comment: Solved my problem of extended display.

Comment: That's what happens when you turn off the 2nd monitor! - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Eclipse. My current version is Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

This periodically happens where the Find/Replace does not work. 
Usually UNDO stops working also.

When this happens, **Ctrl+F**, **Ctrl+Z** do not work, and **Undo Text Change** and **Find/Replace...** are grayed out in the menu.

I tried the above solution **Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...**

That fixed it right away!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When your Eclipse are full with cache that time this problem occurs.

please try to reset perspective setting and then check it.

Just go to menu bar : **Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective** and it will done.